# while loop | reverse counting n....8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to get an automatic reverse counting with user input.
The error is I keep getting the first number in the sequence twice.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print decremental numbers based on user input
#n...8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
echo "Input number"
read k
while test $k != 0
do
    echo "$k"
    k="$(( k - 1 ))"
done
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost standalone_scripts]# . ./decr.sh
Input number
5
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Isn't that just because you can see the input to read?  You can hide it with `read -s` I can't tell if it's portable though.

Comment: You're not getting the first number twice. The first one displayed is the one the user input.

Comment: You can hide the input with `read -s`, but otherwise there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, if you want to simplify it, you can skip the do while loop and just use `seq $k 1`.

Comment: @leekaiinthesky can you count down with `seq`?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII You can but it's not as portable: `seq 10 -1 1`

Comment: @andlrc nice! what do you mean not as portable?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Sure, just added it as an answer so you can see. I think you don't need that `-1` argument, though you should probably trust @andlrc over me.

Comment: @andlrc: (Thanks for the feedback; I've recreated my original comment here with erroneous parts removed.) `read -s` is _not_ portable (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), but, given that this question is tagged `bash`, it shouldn't matter.  It's implied by your 2nd comment, but to make it explicit: `seq` is not a POSIX utility altogether; while it is available on both Linux and BSD/OSX, the implementations differ slightly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as is pointed out in the comments, it's displaying the user input. if you don't like the way it's displayed, then you can switch the order of the subtraction with the echo.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print decremental numbers based on user input
#n...8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
echo "Input number"
read k
while test $k != 0
do
      k="$(( k - 1 ))"
      echo "$k"
done
```

Comment: you are awesome. I tried both and for now switching echo down will wok for me.

Comment: Some things to consider: this displays `0` which the original example wouldn't.  Also, the input value isn't displayed if it comes from something other than the console - redirection, for example.  Similarly, if the output of the script is redirected, it will not include the input value.

Comment: @MichaelBurr good points, the `-s` flag would be simpler/better, but I think [@leekaiinthesky's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37472154/4233593) is the best.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idiomatic Bash reformulation of the script:

- **Using `read -p` prints the prompt string and the user's input *on the same line***, which makes misinterpreting the user's input as being part of the script's output less likely (which is what prompted the OP's question).

  - This is probably preferable to using `read -s`, which *suppresses* echoing the user's input as it is being typed.
- **Using a Bash-native, C-style arithmetic `for` loop (`for (( ...; ...; ... ))`) avoids the concerns about portability of the non-standard external `seq` utility.**

  - For small input numbers, this is probably also faster than using `seq`, and also gives you the flexibility to act on each number individually.
  - For large input numbers, `seq` will be faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Input number: " k

for (( i = k; i >= 1; --i )); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid the newline (and maybe add a `:`) after asking for user input, so that it's clear that the first `5` is user input.

Then here is an example that uses `seq` instead of `while`, though according to @andlrc, `seq` is less portable.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print decremental numbers based on user input
#n...8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
printf "Input number: "
read k
seq $k -1 1
```

Output:

```
$ ./decr.sh 
Input number: 5
5
4
3
2
1
```

**Edit:**

@mklement0's answer is best.

```
read -p "Input number: " k
```

Comment: doesn't work. need to add `-1` to count down, so `seq $((k - 1)) -1 1`

Comment: Really... What platform are you on? It works for me, but maybe this is one of those portability issues mentioned earlier.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04, maybe you should add both examples just in case

Comment: Thanks. Added the `-1`, which seems to be at least *more* portable. :)

Comment: out of curiosity, on what system does `seq $((k - 1)) 1` work? And does `seq $((k - 1)) -1 1` also work the same way?

Comment: I'd thought I was logged into a Linux machine, but I'd actually gotten logged out without realizing, so I was on a Mac. `seq 5 1` and `seq 5 -1 1` do the same thing on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The `read -s` will turn off the `echo` effect of `read`

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print decremental numbers based on user input
#n...8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
echo "Input number"
read -s k
while test $k != 0
do
    echo "$k"
    k="$(( k - 1 ))"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print decremental numbers based on user input
#n...8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
echo "Input number"
read k
seq $((k-1)) -1 1
```

alternatively

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print decremental numbers based on user input
#n...8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
echo "Input number"
read k
while test $k -gt 1; do
    k=$((k-1))
    echo "$k"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is broken:

```
echo "Input number"; read k; while test $k != 0; do
    echo "$k"; k="$(( k - 1 ))"; done
```

Seems to work fine for me:

```
Input number
3   <- this is what you enter
3   <- this is the beginning of the loop
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` and `seq` is the most elegant:

```
for i in `seq 5 -1 1`; do
    echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```